# Beautiful Soup returning nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Hi I am working on a project for my school that involves scraping off the HTML.

However I get none returned when I look for tables. Here is the segment that experiences the issue.

If you need more info I'd be happy to give it to you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import datetime

#This section determines the date of the next Saturday which will go onto the end of     the URL 
d = datetime.date.today() 
while d.weekday() != 5:
    d += datetime.timedelta(1)

#temporary logic for testing when next webpage isn't out
d = "2013-06-01"

#Section that scrapes the data off the webpage
url = "http://www.sydgram.nsw.edu.au/co-curricular/sport/fixtures/" + str(d) + ".php"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup
#Section that grabs the table with stuff in it
table = soup.find('table', {"class": "excel1"})
print table
```

Comment: (this comment is off-topic) join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python please :)

Comment: Nah, I was saying my comment was off topic

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `page` and `soup`? Are they the objects you'd expect? Also, your search may be incorrect if it can't find the table.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I've printed soup and it's good however I get a weird response with "page"  Addinfourl at 39497600 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at (here's some hexadecimal)>

Comment: @akkatracker That's because you didn't call `.read()`, which you actually don't need to do as `BeautifulSoup()` seems to fix that :)

Comment: @Haidro figured that out as BS states that in their documentation, but still get that error.

Comment: @akkatracker It's not an error. It's what the instance's `__repr__` output is. Take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr)

Comment: I'm referring to my initial none returned

Comment: @akkatracker so it doesn't work still?

Comment: Nah it still doesn't work @Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is expecting a String of HTML. What you provide is a response object.

fetch the html from the response:

```
 html = page.read()
```

and then hand html over to beautifulsoup or pass it directly however you like.

In addition id would be advisable to read the following two links:

[urllib2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

[BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Still returning, when I print soup I get the HTML but when searching for a table I get none

Comment: I will have look at it when I get home.  :-)

Comment: Have you tried running it with python3? It works for me just fine!
http://pastebin.com/1i0Sm1j3

Comment: Sorry for responding so late :-/