# Beautiful Soup returning empty set

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, redhat

Beautiful Soup is working fine on a local machine, but not working on another server.

```
import urllib2
import bs4

url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
html = url.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup
```

Printing Html outputs google's webpage correctly. Printing soup returns empty.

On local it works fine, however on this redhat machine it returns empty.

Is this something to do with installing a parser? I looked up some other possible solutions and they mentioned installing a parser, but no luck thus far.

This solution [Beautiful Soup returning nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917124/beautiful-soup-returning-nothing) doesn't apply to my problem

Comment: well, what are the differences between your local machine and your server ?

Comment: As far as I've understood your question, in both machines the html is read OK, but in your local machine you get some output from bs4, and in the server you get nothing. Do you get `None`, or an empty string?

Comment: Local is running windows, python 2.7. Server running redhat python 2.7

Comment: José Tomás Tocino, it's an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Just to prove you that your case is unique and there is nothing to do with Redhat.

I kicked out an micro Redhat instance from AWS and here is the complete process from SSH into that brand new redhat machines. 
[image]

(1) Here i installed beautifulsoup4 on the new machine:

```
$ ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@awsip
The authenticity of host 'awsip' cant be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'awsip' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
[ec2-user@awsip ~]$ sudo easy_install beautifulsoup4
Searching for beautifulsoup4
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/
...
Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4
Finished processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4
```

(2) I opened up python and get the output from google both in `html` and `soup`

```
[ec2-user@awsip ~]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 27 2013, 05:35:12)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print html[:100]
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta content="Search t
>>> print soup.prettify()[:100]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
 <head>
  <meta content="Se
```

To debug it is the fault of urllib2 or bs4: 
try run this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1">numberone</div>
<div id="2">numbertwo</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

print BeautifulSoup(html).find('div', {"id":"1"})
```

If you beautifulsoup is installed successfully, you will get the expected output like below:

```
<div id="1">numberone</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm also using aws. It's a pretty confusing setup as it's used by other mates at work. I guess one of my questions would be how to find the problem of why Beautiful Soup doesn't work

Comment: @Darthyogurt There are two main steps in this whole proces. First download the html using urllib2 and then build the tree using beautifulsoup. Maybe you can hardcode a simple html file and see if beautifulsoup will build the tree. See the updated post.

Comment: So I've copied the sample code and running the script returns a None. I'm assuming it is a bs4 problem. Which is weird because it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: @Darthyogurt There is definitely something wrong with your bs4 installation. The default Python version for redhat should be 2.6, you mentioned you have python2.7 and there is maybe something wrong installing libraries to different versions of Python. However, if you have no problem importing the bs4 library.. it should work and beautifulsoup4 has a default parser coming along which should work for the debug code. Can you provide more information for us to help you?

Comment: You're absolutely right about redhat having only 2.6. I realized i'm not running python 2.7 whilst running my script. I realize that my problem now is that I have to run it as 2.7.  I re ran your script under python 2.7 and soup worked! The problem is that soup doesn't run correctly under 2.6 under my machine

Comment: @Darthyogurt bs4 works under 2.6 for sure. My answer basically proves that I think. Maybe you can try `sudo easy_install beautifulsoup4` again? if not, remove and build from source.

Comment: I've tried to delete the files in the library /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ anything to do with bs4 and beautifulsoup egg.  Did a "import bs4" to make sure that the package didn't exist. Reinstalled using easy_install and it didn't work. Deleted those packages. Then tried python setup.py install with the package off their website, didn't work either.  I am conjecturing that the problem is python with its install. Seems all other packages are working fine.

Comment: Well, I will say assuming you did not make any simple mistake a long the way(like calling the wrong python/install to the wrong place... etc). There is really not that much I can do to help. Anyway, all the information that might be helpful will be in this way... Maybe you can talk to your company's admin and he will figure it out.